Relationship between $C(X;\text{Lip}_0(Y))$ and $C(X \times Y)$
Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m,Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be subsets of Euclidean spaces, $0\in Y$, and let $\text{Lip}_0(Y)$ the space of Lipschitz functions $f:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$, equipped with the Lipschitz norm
$$\quad \|f\|_{\text{Lip}} = \|\nabla f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{y_1 \neq y_2} \left|\frac{f(y_1) - f(y_2)}{\|y_1 - y_2\|}\right| $$
$\text{Lip}_0(Y)$ being a Banach space, we can then define the set of continuous $\text{Lip}_0(Y)$-valued functions on $X$, namely $C(X;\text{Lip}_0(Y)) $
My question is: what is the relationship between this space and
$$ C_{\text{Lip}_0} := \{ f\in C(X\times Y) : f(x,\cdot) \in \text{Lip}_0(Y) \ \forall x\in X \} ?$$
It is pretty clear that $C_{\text{Lip}_0} \subseteq C(X;\text{Lip}_0(Y)) $, but does equality hold? I tried to build a simple counterexample of a function in $C(X;\text{Lip}_0(Y)) $ but not in $ C_{\text{Lip}_0}$ like this:
take $X=[-1,1], Y=[0,+\infty)$, and define
$$ f_x(y) = \begin{cases} y \ \text{ if } x<0 \\
-y \ \text{ if } x\ge0 \end{cases} $$
but this turns out to be discontinuous (if $x_n\to 0^-$ then $f_{x_n}=\text{Id}$ for all $n$, while $f_0=-\text{Id}$, and $\|2 \text{Id}\|_{\text{Lip}}=2$). And, at least for one-dimensional domains, it seems to me that I can't do much better than this, being $0$ pinned in $0$.
Maybe, taking $X,Y$ in higher dimensional spaces could help building the counterexample?

By $C_{\text{Lip}_0}\subseteq C(X;\text{Lip}0(Y))$ you actually mean the inclusion where you treat $f\in C{\text{Lip}_0}$ as an element of $C(X;\text{Lip}_0(Y))$ by defining $\hat{f}(x)(y) = f(x, y)$.

Under very mild condition of local compactness of $Y$, the map $f\mapsto \hat{f}$ is a bijection between $C(X\times Y)$ and $C(X; C(Y))$. You only need that $Y$ is locally compact, for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ this means sets which are intersections of open and closed set. This should restrict to equality in your case.

@Jakobian Yes, exactly. I think of both sets as subsets of real valued functions on $X \times Y$.

@Jakobian Thank you for your reply. $C(Y)$ would be the set of continuous functions on $Y$, with the infinity norm, I would imagine. So, you say that, if $Y$ locally compact, $C(X;C(Y))=C(X\times Y)$. This indeed seems to imply that $\text{Lip}_0=C(X;\text{Lip}_0(Y)$ - I will ponder it for a second but seems straightforward.

@Jakobian Are you sure of your hypothesis? In particular, are you sure you don't need anything on $X$? I understand it's probably trivial but, at the moment, I can't visualize it, sorry.

Ah yes sorry. The topology on $C(Y)$ here should be that of compact convergence i.e. uniform convergence on compact sets. For this to apply to your example one has to check if this coincides with the topology given by your norm. I don't think it necessarily does.

Thank you very much for your input, I'll think about it

From the paper I found, for uniform convergence on bounded subsets to imply Lipschitz norm convergence, one would have to work with a discrete space such that there is one common radius such that all balls of this radius are singletons, so it seems like my comments don't really help here.

I was hoping to leverage the fact that if $f \in C(X;\text{Lip}0(Y))$, then the composition with the norm is continuous: $|f(\cdot)|{\text{Lip}}\in C(X)$.
